# Binding DataSet to a ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I've a problem. I'm not a WPF master, but I've a homework to complete.

I'm trying to bind my dataset from my database to a combobox.

I've done this in Windows Form Application, but I don't know how to in WPF.
I've searched across the whole internet, but I'm a kind of slow person. :)

If you would help me, that would be great.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Válassz kategóriát!" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Capture it" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <ComboBox Name="category_select" ItemsSource="{Binding}"></ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
private void show_categories()
{
    category_select.Items.Clear();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HQ\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BGIQuiz;Integrated Security=True");
    try
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter category_data = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TYPE", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        category_data.Fill(ds, "t");

        category_select.DataContext = ds.Tables["t"].DefaultView;
        category_select.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables["t"].Columns["description"].ToString();
        category_select.SelectedValuePath = ds.Tables["t"].Columns["type_id"].ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Database:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XgYS.png]

Comment: Try to remove the defaultview getter

Comment: Try looking up how to use the `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the name of your columns are "description" and "type_id" you can just do this:

```
category_select.DisplayMemberPath = "description";
category_select.SelectedValuePath = "type_id";
```

As a suggestion, you could set the ItemSource property instead the DataContext in your code begind:

```
 category_select.ItemSource= ds.Tables["t"].DefaultView;
```

So, you don't have to set that property (ItemSeource) in your view:

```
 <ComboBox Name="category_select"></ComboBox>
```

Also you can do this:

```
 <ComboBox Name="category_select" DisplayMemberPath = "description" SelectedValuePath = "type_id"></ComboBox>
```

And don't set those properties in your code behind.

Answer (score 1):

```
category_select.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["t"].DefaultView;
category_select.DisplayMemberPath = "description";
category_select.SelectedValuePath = "type_id";
```