# Selecting the GSM modem from connected USB devices and save it in a SQL Server database for future use

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Sending SMS is a functional requirement of my developing software. I'm using C# and SQL Server.

I have used some codes for sending SMS and it really works.

Problem is: each time I send a SMS I have to insert the port name (eg: COM1, COM2, etc) into a textbox.

I want to select the connected device through a combobox (not such as COM1, COM2,.. but a user frienly name) and save it in a SQL Server database without selecting each time I send SMS (or auto detect even without searching for the device name)

This is the code I'm using for sending the SMS.

```
private void btnSendMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            SmsSubmitPdu pdu;
            byte dcs = (byte) DataCodingScheme.GeneralCoding.Alpha7BitDefault;
            pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu(txtMessage.Text,txtTelephoneNumber.Text,dcs);
            int time =1;

            for(int i=0; i<time; i++)
            {
                comm.SendMessage(pdu);

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Modem is not available!");
        }
    }
}
```

Connecting to the relevant port is done by another code.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think that a whole Database setup for this is an overkill (given the assumption that you would only use this database for the modem settings?).

A first approach could be that you create a ComboBox with different Item.Text / Item.Value properties.

Quickly drawn example:

```
ComboBox cbModem = new ComboBox();
ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
cbi.Text("My friendly display string :)");
cbi.Value("COM1");
cbModem.Items.Add(cbi);
```

You then can get the selected value by

```
string selValue = (ComboboxItem)cbModem.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Already there is a database . Sending SMS and Emails is only a part of this software. When using the program, I can set COM1, COM2, etc as I know the exact port where the device is connected. But, think if someone connect the devices to USB port as his own choice, pre-defined port names may give errors, as they are not connected to the ports where the program is expecting.

Comment: I still struggle to see the full logic here. But since you already have a database (to which you can connect etc) you would simply set up a table and feed your Combobox control with its data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760385/binding-dataset-to-a-combobox-in-wpf

Comment: Here I've illustrated what I'm trying to explain :) (http://oi67.tinypic.com/1zpgoxw.jpg) . If I could do this kind of think there's no need of setting the COM1, COM2, .... again and again. It will need only to change when the devices are removed and connected to another USB port (or adding new devices removing old ones) . Will you be able to give a solution for this?